# Do I need geckoDriver if I am using selenium standalone service in wdio.conf.ts?

Tags: typescript, firefox, webdriver-io, geckodriver

I am using web driver IO for testing. Parallel execution is working as expected.

I was wondering Do I need a GeckoDriver in my root folder if i am using Selenium standalone service to run test in firefox?
Please find the screenshot below:
[image]

Comment: I figured it out Gecko Driver is not needed if Selenium standalone service is being used.Tests run fine if i delete Geckodriver from my root folder.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium standalone downloads browser drivers for you (but now browsers themselves).